# The stock item was unable to be saved. Please try again. Tha

Tags: backend, magento2.4.6

I have the same issue with the last version 2.4.6

It doesn't work when I check a product.

---

check errors

In the system.log

#53 {main} {"exception":"[object] (Magento\Framework\Exception\CouldNotSaveException(code: 0): The stock item was unable to be saved. Please try again. at /home/jakarts/public_html/vendor/magento/module-catalog-inventory/Model/Stock/StockItemRepository.php:196)
[previous exception] [object] (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(code: 0): Could not ping search engine: No alive nodes found in your cluster at /home/jakarts/public_html/vendor/magento/module-elasticsearch/Model/Adapter/Elasticsearch.php:196)"} []

Can you explain me this language please?

Comment: Please provide the context, how are you trying to save the stock? Is it via admin or API? Have you checked any logs?

Comment: please check your elasticsearch status

Comment: Via admin @Ahmed

Comment: elasticsearch not found when I run to the CLI @Pramod

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as per your comment make sure you have either one of elasticsearch or opensearch is configured after configuring follow steps to set it up as search engine in magento.

```
php bin/magento config:store:set catalog/search/engine elasticsearch7

php bin/magento config:store:set catalog/search/elasticsearch7_server_hostname localhost

php bin/magento catalog/search/elasticsearch7_server_port 9200
```

here i have given you steps for elastic search make sure to change the values for opensearch for your search engine port and host.

Then reindex. hope it will help

Comment: Yes, I'm going to try run this code by CLI. In fact, there is not a sample data installed. Maybe it's for that.

Answer (score 0):

Please check below

Run permission command `chmod -R 777 var/ pub/ generated/`

1. Check Magento log
2. Check server log
3. Check browser network tab

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your elastic search isn't working. You can check that from the admin panel Go to **Stores -> Configuration -> Catalog -> Catalog Search -> Click on test button**.
[image]

Comment: When I run by cli php bin/magento module:status ; Magento_Elasticsearch
Magento_Elasticsearch7 is enabled

Comment: "php bin/magento module:status " shows the status of the module with the given name.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, OpenSearch is on time.

I never set up Open Seach to AWS

https://opensearch.org/docs/latest/install-and-configure/install-opensearch/index/

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hPc1ecsxRBU

Screenshoot:
[image]
[image]

Is this a good path?

Answer (score 0):

```
List of enabled modules:

Magento_Store
Magento_Config
Magento_AdminAnalytics
Magento_AdminNotification
Magento_AdobeIms
Magento_AdobeImsApi
Magento_AdobeStockAdminUi
Magento_MediaGallery
Magento_AdobeStockAssetApi
Magento_AdobeStockClient
Magento_AdobeStockClientApi
Magento_AdobeStockImage
Magento_Directory
Magento_AdobeStockImageApi
Magento_AdvancedPricingImportExport
Magento_Theme
Magento_Amqp
Magento_Backend
Magento_User
Magento_Authorization
Magento_Eav
Magento_Customer
Magento_AdminAdobeIms
Magento_Backup
Magento_Indexer
Magento_GraphQl
Magento_BundleImportExport
Magento_CacheInvalidate
Magento_Variable
Magento_Cms
Magento_Rule
Magento_Security
Magento_CmsGraphQl
Magento_EavGraphQl
Magento_Search
Magento_CatalogImportExport
Magento_Catalog
Magento_CatalogInventory
Magento_CatalogPageBuilderAnalytics
Magento_CatalogRule
Magento_Msrp
Magento_CatalogRuleGraphQl
Magento_CatalogSearch
Magento_CatalogUrlRewrite
Magento_StoreGraphQl
Magento_MediaStorage
Magento_Quote
Magento_SalesSequence
Magento_CheckoutAgreementsGraphQl
Magento_MediaGalleryUi
Magento_CatalogGraphQl
Magento_CmsPageBuilderAnalytics
Magento_CmsUrlRewrite
Magento_CmsUrlRewriteGraphQl
Magento_CompareListGraphQl
Magento_Integration
Magento_Payment
Magento_Sales
Magento_QuoteGraphQl
Magento_Checkout
Magento_Contact
Magento_Cookie
Magento_Cron
Magento_Csp
Magento_Widget
Magento_Robots
Magento_Analytics
Magento_Downloadable
Magento_CustomerGraphQl
Magento_CustomerImportExport
Magento_Deploy
Magento_Developer
Magento_Dhl
Magento_AdvancedSearch
Magento_DirectoryGraphQl
Magento_DownloadableGraphQl
Magento_CustomerDownloadableGraphQl
Magento_ImportExport
Magento_Bundle
Magento_CatalogCustomerGraphQl
Magento_Elasticsearch
Magento_Elasticsearch7
Magento_Email
Magento_EncryptionKey
Magento_Fedex
Magento_GiftMessage
Magento_GiftMessageGraphQl
Magento_GoogleAdwords
Magento_GoogleAnalytics
Magento_GoogleGtag
Magento_Ui
Magento_GoogleShoppingAds
Magento_BundleGraphQl
Magento_PageCache
Magento_GroupedProduct
Magento_GroupedImportExport
Magento_GroupedCatalogInventory
Magento_GroupedProductGraphQl
Magento_DownloadableImportExport
Magento_Captcha
Magento_InstantPurchase
Magento_CatalogAnalytics
Magento_Inventory
Magento_InventoryAdminUi
Magento_InventoryAdvancedCheckout
Magento_InventoryApi
Magento_InventoryBundleImportExport
Magento_InventoryBundleProduct
Magento_InventoryBundleProductAdminUi
Magento_InventoryBundleProductIndexer
Magento_InventoryCatalog
Magento_InventorySales
Magento_InventoryCatalogAdminUi
Magento_InventoryCatalogApi
Magento_InventoryCatalogFrontendUi
Magento_InventoryCatalogSearch
Magento_InventoryCatalogSearchBundleProduct
Magento_InventoryCatalogSearchConfigurableProduct
Magento_ConfigurableProduct
Magento_ConfigurableProductGraphQl
Magento_InventoryConfigurableProduct
Magento_InventoryConfigurableProductIndexer
Magento_InventoryConfiguration
Magento_InventoryConfigurationApi
Magento_InventoryDistanceBasedSourceSelection
Magento_InventoryDistanceBasedSourceSelectionAdminUi
Magento_InventoryDistanceBasedSourceSelectionApi
Magento_InventoryElasticsearch
Magento_InventoryExportStockApi
Magento_InventoryIndexer
Magento_InventorySalesApi
Magento_InventoryGroupedProduct
Magento_InventoryGroupedProductAdminUi
Magento_InventoryGroupedProductIndexer
Magento_InventoryImportExport
Magento_InventoryInStorePickupApi
Magento_InventoryInStorePickupAdminUi
Magento_InventorySourceSelectionApi
Magento_InventoryInStorePickup
Magento_InventoryInStorePickupGraphQl
Magento_Shipping
Magento_InventoryInStorePickupShippingApi
Magento_InventoryInStorePickupQuoteGraphQl
Magento_InventoryInStorePickupSales
Magento_InventoryInStorePickupSalesApi
Magento_InventoryInStorePickupQuote
Magento_InventoryInStorePickupShipping
Magento_InventoryInStorePickupShippingAdminUi
Magento_Multishipping
Magento_Webapi
Magento_InventoryCache
Magento_InventoryLowQuantityNotification
Magento_Reports
Magento_InventoryLowQuantityNotificationApi
Magento_InventoryMultiDimensionalIndexerApi
Magento_InventoryProductAlert
Magento_InventoryQuoteGraphQl
Magento_InventoryRequisitionList
Magento_InventoryReservations
Magento_InventoryReservationCli
Magento_InventoryReservationsApi
Magento_InventoryExportStock
Magento_InventorySalesAdminUi
Magento_CatalogInventoryGraphQl
Magento_InventorySalesAsyncOrder
Magento_InventorySalesFrontendUi
Magento_InventorySetupFixtureGenerator
Magento_InventoryShipping
Magento_InventoryShippingAdminUi
Magento_InventorySourceDeductionApi
Magento_InventorySourceSelection
Magento_InventoryInStorePickupFrontend
Magento_InventorySwatchesFrontendUi
Magento_InventoryVisualMerchandiser
Magento_InventoryWishlist
Magento_JwtFrameworkAdapter
Magento_JwtUserToken
Magento_LayeredNavigation
Magento_LoginAsCustomer
Magento_LoginAsCustomerAdminUi
Magento_LoginAsCustomerApi
Magento_LoginAsCustomerAssistance
Magento_LoginAsCustomerFrontendUi
Magento_LoginAsCustomerGraphQl
Magento_LoginAsCustomerLog
Magento_LoginAsCustomerPageCache
Magento_LoginAsCustomerQuote
Magento_LoginAsCustomerSales
Magento_Marketplace
Magento_MediaContent
Magento_MediaContentApi
Magento_MediaContentCatalog
Magento_MediaContentCms
Magento_MediaContentSynchronization
Magento_MediaContentSynchronizationApi
Magento_MediaContentSynchronizationCatalog
Magento_MediaContentSynchronizationCms
Magento_AdobeStockAsset
Magento_MediaGalleryApi
Magento_MediaGalleryCatalog
Magento_MediaGalleryCatalogIntegration
Magento_MediaGalleryCatalogUi
Magento_MediaGalleryCmsUi
Magento_MediaGalleryIntegration
Magento_MediaGalleryMetadata
Magento_MediaGalleryMetadataApi
Magento_MediaGalleryRenditions
Magento_MediaGalleryRenditionsApi
Magento_MediaGallerySynchronization
Magento_MediaGallerySynchronizationApi
Magento_MediaGallerySynchronizationMetadata
Magento_AdobeStockImageAdminUi
Magento_MediaGalleryUiApi
Magento_CatalogWidget
Magento_MessageQueue
Magento_ConfigurableImportExport
Magento_MsrpConfigurableProduct
Magento_MsrpGroupedProduct
Magento_InventoryInStorePickupMultishipping
Magento_MysqlMq
Magento_NewRelicReporting
Magento_Newsletter
Magento_NewsletterGraphQl
Magento_OfflinePayments
Magento_SalesRule
Magento_OpenSearch
Magento_Sitemap
Magento_PageBuilder
Magento_PageBuilderAnalytics
Magento_GraphQlCache
Magento_CardinalCommerce
Magento_PaymentGraphQl
Magento_Vault
Magento_Paypal
Magento_PaypalGraphQl
Magento_Persistent
Magento_ProductAlert
Magento_ProductVideo
Magento_CheckoutAgreements
Magento_QuoteAnalytics
Magento_QuoteBundleOptions
Magento_QuoteConfigurableOptions
Magento_QuoteDownloadableLinks
Magento_InventoryConfigurableProductAdminUi
Magento_ReCaptchaAdminUi
Magento_ReCaptchaCheckout
Magento_ReCaptchaCheckoutSalesRule
Magento_ReCaptchaContact
Magento_ReCaptchaCustomer
Magento_ReCaptchaFrontendUi
Magento_ReCaptchaMigration
Magento_ReCaptchaNewsletter
Magento_ReCaptchaPaypal
Magento_ReCaptchaReview
Magento_ReCaptchaSendFriend
Magento_ReCaptchaStorePickup
Magento_ReCaptchaUi
Magento_ReCaptchaUser
Magento_ReCaptchaValidation
Magento_ReCaptchaValidationApi
Magento_ReCaptchaVersion2Checkbox
Magento_ReCaptchaVersion2Invisible
Magento_ReCaptchaVersion3Invisible
Magento_ReCaptchaWebapiApi
Magento_ReCaptchaWebapiGraphQl
Magento_ReCaptchaWebapiRest
Magento_ReCaptchaWebapiUi
Magento_RelatedProductGraphQl
Magento_ReleaseNotification
Magento_RemoteStorage
Magento_InventoryLowQuantityNotificationAdminUi
Magento_RequireJs
Magento_Review
Magento_ReviewAnalytics
Magento_ReviewGraphQl
Magento_AwsS3
Magento_Rss
Magento_PageBuilderAdminAnalytics
Magento_CatalogRuleConfigurable
Magento_SalesAnalytics
Magento_SalesGraphQl
Magento_SalesInventory
Magento_OfflineShipping
Magento_ConfigurableProductSales
Magento_UrlRewrite
Magento_UrlRewriteGraphQl
Magento_CustomerAnalytics
Magento_Securitytxt
Magento_SendFriend
Magento_SendFriendGraphQl
Magento_InventoryInStorePickupSalesAdminUi
Magento_AwsS3PageBuilder
Magento_InventoryGraphQl
Magento_CatalogCmsGraphQl
Magento_Swagger
Magento_SwaggerWebapi
Magento_SwaggerWebapiAsync
Magento_Swatches
Magento_SwatchesGraphQl
Magento_SwatchesLayeredNavigation
Magento_Tax
Magento_TaxGraphQl
Magento_TaxImportExport
Magento_ThemeGraphQl
Magento_Translation
Magento_GoogleOptimizer
Magento_Ups
Magento_SampleData
Magento_CatalogUrlRewriteGraphQl
Magento_AsynchronousOperations
Magento_Usps
Magento_InventoryConfigurableProductFrontendUi
Magento_PaypalCaptcha
Magento_VaultGraphQl
Magento_Version
Magento_InventoryInStorePickupWebapiExtension
Magento_WebapiAsync
Magento_WebapiSecurity
Magento_Weee
Magento_WeeeGraphQl
Magento_CurrencySymbol
Magento_Wishlist
Magento_WishlistAnalytics
Magento_WishlistGraphQl
PayPal_Braintree
PayPal_BraintreeGraphQl
Temando_ShippingRemover

List of disabled modules:
Magento_TwoFactorAuth
Magento_AdminAdobeImsTwoFactorAuth
```

[image]
@Anurag
When I run :php bin/magento setup:upgrade

The answer is:
Could not validate a connection to the OpenSearch. No alive nodes found in your cluster
[image]