# i am trying to create a product on magento to but it will throw me an error

Tags: magento2, elasticsearch

[image: when i am trying to create product it will give me and error]

[image: Elasticsearch error]

this error occur because of issue with Elasticsearch and many times i am changed the Elasticsearch configuration and re-install but after many try it give me same error

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code , how to create a simple product in Magento 2.4.6 :

```
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Type;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product as ProductModel;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product as ResourceModel;
use Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockRegistryInterface;
....

    /** @var ProductModel */
    protected ProductModel $product;

    /** @var ResourceModel */
    protected ResourceModel $resourceModelProduct;

    /** @var StockRegistryInterface */
    protected StockRegistryInterface $stockRegistry;
....
    public function __construct(
        ProductModel $product,
        ResourceModel $resourceModelProduct,
        StockRegistryInterface $stockRegistry
    ){
        $this->product = $product;
        $this->resourceModelProduct = $resourceModelProduct;
        $this->stockRegistry = $stockRegistry;
    }

    public function createProduct()
    {
            $productData = [
                'sku'               => 'My SKU',
                'name'              => 'My title',
                'attribute_set_id'  => 4, // Set the attribute set ID for the 'Default' set
                'price'             => 100,
                'status'            => 1, // Enabled
                'visibility'        => 4, // Catalog, Search
                'type_id'           => Type::DEFAULT_TYPE,
                'description'       => 'My Description',
                'url_key'           => 'myurl',
                'page_layout'       => '1column',
                'category_ids'      => [1,2,3,4,5,6,7] // add your category IDS
            ];
            $product->setCustomAttribute('fancy_custom_attribute', 123); // set your custom attribute, if you have one, otherwise remove this line
            $product = $this->product->setData($productData);
            $product->setWebsiteIds([1]);  //add your website ID
            $this->resourceModelProduct->save($product);

            $this->updateProductStock($product->getId(), $sku, 10); // change 10 to your stock
     }

     public function updateProductStock(int $productId, string $sku, int $newStockQty): void
     {
            $stockItem = $this->stockRegistry->getStockItem($productId);
            $stockItem->setQty($newStockQty);
            $stockItem->setIsInStock(1);
            $stockItem->setManageStock(1);
            $this->stockRegistry->updateStockItemBySku($sku, $stockItem);
     }
```

Of course the StockRegistryInterface is deprecated, but it will work. Also this script will not work for MSI.

Hope this post will help you to continue your work and maybe change it based on your needs.

Good luck !

Comment: i dont want a code there is some error while i am trying to create product on my magento store after the Elasticsearch is active

Comment: have you check this answer https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/368327/the-stock-item-was-unable-to-be-saved-please-try-again-tha